A category has local initial objects if and only if it has a coreflective subgroupoid
Given a category $C$, say that $C$ has local initial objects if every slice category of $C$ has an initial object.
In category theory, there are two different meanings of "locally": one applying to Hom-sets, and the other to slice categories. The former applies to "locally small", while the latter applies to "locally cartesian closed". The latter meaning is used above.
Then, is it true that a category $C$ has local initial objects if and only if $C$ has a coreflective subcategory that is a groupoid?
For the "only if" direction, let $D$ be the full subcategory of objects $X$ of $C$ for which the slice category $C/X$ has a zero object (note that $(X, \mathrm{id}_X)$ is always terminal, so it also needs to be initial for it to be a zero object). Then, for any object $X$ of $C$, the initial object of $C/X$ should give a coreflection of $X$ in $D$. Also, every morphism in $D$ should be an isomorphism (making $D$ a subgroupoid of $C$).
Conversely, for the "if" direction, let $D$ be a coreflective subgroupoid of $C$. Then, for any object $X$ of $C$, the coreflection of $X$ in $D$ should give an initial object of $C/X$.
Is the above correct?

For the "only if" direction. Suppose $\epsilon_X\colon IX\to X$ and $\epsilon_Y\colon IY\to Y$ are initial in $\mathcal C/X$ and $\mathcal C/Y$ respectively. Then to each morphism $g\colon IY\to X$ is associated a unique morphism $h\colon IX\to IY$ for which $\epsilon_X=g\circ h$. But then $\epsilon_Y\circ h\colon IX\to IY\to Y$ has an associated unique morphism $g'\colon IY\to IX$ for which $\epsilon_Y=\epsilon_Y\circ h\circ g'$, and $\epsilon_X\circ g'\colon IY\to IX$ has associated a unique morphism $h'\colon IX\to IY$ for which $\epsilon_X=\epsilon_X\circ g'\circ h'$.
It follows that $g'\colon IY\to IX$ is invertible with inverse $h=h'$ and so unique such that $g=\epsilon_X\circ g'$. Consequently, if $\mathcal C/X$ has an intiial object for each $X$, then the full subcategory of objects $I$ for which there is a morphism $I\to X$ that is an initial obect of $\mathcal C/X$ is coreflective and a groupoid.

For the "if" direction.
If $\epsilon_X\colon UJX\to X$ and $\epsilon_Y\colon UJY\to Y$ are components of coreflections along a functor $U$, then $g\colon UJX\to Y$ factors as $\epsilon_Y\circ Ug'\colon UJX\to UJY\to Y$ for a unique $g'\colon JX\to JY$, and satisfies $\epsilon_X=f\circ g$ if and only if $\epsilon_X=f\circ\epsilon_Y\circ Ug'=\epsilon_X\circ UJf\circ Ug'$, i.e. $Jf\circ g'=\mathrm{id}_{JX}$.
Thus morphisms from $\epsilon_X\colon UJX\to X$ to $f\colon Y\to X$ in $\mathcal C/X$ are in bijection with sections of $Jf\colon JY\to JX$. It follows that, if coreflections $\epsilon_Y\colon UJY\to Y$ exist for each $Y$ with a morphism $f\colon Y\to X$, then $\epsilon_X\colon UJX\to X$ is an initial object in $\mathcal C/X$ if and only if $Jf\colon JY\to JX$ has a unique section for each $f\colon X\to Y$.
Consequently, the components $\epsilon_X\colon UJX\to X$ of a counit of an adjunction $U\dashv J$ are initial objects of $\mathcal C/X$ for every $X$ if and only if $Jf$ has a unique section for each morphism $f$. In particular this is the case if the image of $J$ is a groupoid.
